# vim does not recognize my filetype

Tags: vim, configuration, file-type

I am using a plugin that redefine a filetype:

`cat ~/.vim/bundle/kdb-vim/filetype.vim`

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.k            setfiletype k
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.q            setfiletype q
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.s            setfiletype sql
augroup END
```

And in my vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off                                            
                                                                                                    
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle                                                                       
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Align                                                                        
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vim-R-plugin                                                                 
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim                                                                    
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/minibufexpl.vim                                                              
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/nerdcommenter                                                                
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree                                                                     
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/syntastic                                                                    
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips                                                                    
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive                                                                 
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/screen                                                                       
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/kdb-vim                                                                      
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/statquantPlugin                                                              
                                            
filetype plugin on                                                                                  
filetype indent on                                                                                  
syntax   on
```

When I try to open a `*q` file the filetype is not detected.
Then I commented out

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
```

So there the file is detected but then when I start writting some stuff and reopen the file the filetype swith to `CONF`. I need it as I `statquantPlugin` I configured something to act based on the filetype.

NOTE: I do not have access to the `$VIM` directory files

What can I do to have the `filetype` right ?
Regards

## I changed

```
$ cat .vim/bundle/kdb-vim/ftdetect/myFiletype.vim 
" my filetype file
"if exists("did_load_filetypes")
"  finish
"endif
"augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.k            setfiletype k
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.q            setfiletype q
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.s            setfiletype sql
"augroup END
```

NOW working

Comment: What's with all those runtimepath modifications?

Comment: I am behind a firewall so I can't do BundleInstall => I took the .vim directory from somewhere else (where I could run BundleInstall), so I have to add the bundles to the rtp (well at least if I do not it does not work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filetype.vim` is the main filetype detection script; you shouldn't override it. Instead, put (only the `au! BufRead,BufNewFile` lines, the include guard and `:augroup` isn't necessary there) this into a file `~/.vim/bundle/kdb-vim/ftdetect/myfiletypes.vim`. See `:help ftdetect`.

Comment: Drop the `:if exists(...)`, too.